# How to remove Image that is showing through the dropdown on top of it?

Tags: lightning, aura

I have a drop down that opens on top of a search box. But the search icon is showing through the dropdown box. I have the following CSS for the dropdown content:

```css
.THIS .dropdown-content{
  /*display: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #23395b;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Acually I just figured it out myself. I had to change the z-index for this dropdown to 2 and the search box underneath to 1. And that fixed the issue